# How can I get Entity Framework and WCF to work with transactions? Okay...what's the secret?

Tags: wcf, oracle, entity-framework, transactions

I've been trying several different ways in order to get a simple set of transactions to work for a simple WCF client/server situation.  My WCF server has a class level declaration of the Entity Framework class for my database access and several methods to modify data and a method to SaveChanges.  I'm using the Oracle Data Access (ODP.NET).

For instance I want to call a modification from the client and then a separate call to save the changes in the WCF service.  It doesn't work. Basically, everything executes fine, but when the second call to save the changes is made, the WCF service no longer has the original context and therefore no changes are saved (and, consequently, the previous call that made the changes was automatically rolled back).

I'm utilizing Transaction scope around both operations in my client and executing Complete() after done.  My WCF services have OperationContract's that use `[TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Mandatory)]` and those method implementations use `[OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true, TransactionAutoComplete = true)]`.  Finally, my web config is configured with a wsHttpBinding that has the `transactionFlow` property set to True.

I'm having no luck.  No matter what I try, when I try hitting the service for the follow-up save, the EF context is already renewed.

Comment: Not all bindings support transactions. http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/Transactions-in-WCF-and-NET.id-305253.html

Comment: How are you handling session between calls?  WCF is stateless by default, so unless you're directing WCF to do something with the state you may be losing something.

Comment: Are entities generated by edmx or poco generated

Comment: Just because you are using transactions in WCF would not guarantee transactions in every scope, are you storing the datacontext in the transactional state ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with transaction. Transaction works on transactional resource but without calling `SaveChanges` in the first request there was no transactional resource active because EF context is not part of the transaction - the database is and the database is affected only when you call `SaveChanges`. To make this work you don't need distributed transactions. You need session-full service and store the EF context in the service instance. It a client uses the same client proxy instance to communicate with the service for all requests the communication will be handled by the same service instance = same EF context instance which will remember changes from previous calls.

IMHO this is very bad architecture. Simply don't use it. Expose specialized methods on WCF service which will do changes and save them. If you need to execute these methods in transaction with other transactional resources use the real distributed transaction.

Comment: I respect your answer. And, I was afraid that would be the answer. Bummer. Unfortunately, it demotes the use of my service. For instance, if I want to allow users of my service to create orders and/or create/modify extraneous elements to those orders (such as product details) and allow them to tie themselves together in a single transaction if doing both actions, it can't be done in an atomic (multiple pass) fashion. That sucks but I do understand what you're saying.  Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

this might be a reason. Since your are making an update in the different context. context doesn't know that the object is update to have say the context that the object is modified and then you call savechnages(). See if it helps

Comment: You are correct.  Basically, this is what the previous responder noted.  It's a shame I can't do it without making the Context and service stateful.